# Ruby array to hash with params

Tags: ruby, json

I have an array:

```
 arr = ["dog", "cat", "eel"]
```

And I'd like to convert it into a JSON like so:

```
'{"dog": {}, "cat": {}, "eel": {} }'
```

And NOT:

```
'{"dog"=> {}, "cat"=> {}, "eel"=> {} }'
```

I've tried using:

```
res = arr.each_with_object({}) { |k,h| h[k] = {} }
```

I feel like I'm missing something quite obvious. Is there a way to single quote it upon response?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below code :

```
require 'json'

arr = ["dog", "cat", "eel"]
puts Hash[arr.each_with_object({}).to_a].to_json
# >> {"dog":{},"cat":{},"eel":{}}
puts Hash[arr.map{|e| [e,{}]}].to_json # you can do this way also
# >> {"dog":{},"cat":{},"eel":{}}
```